# How to pass a lot of data to Plumber in R

Tags: r, plumber

I would like to play with the `plumber` library by making an app that takes 14 days of historical data and returns an exponential smoothing forecast.

The problem is I am somewhat unfamiliar with passing a lot of data (a parameter with multiple values) to an API. My questions can be summarized as follows:

1. How should I prepare the data in R to be passed to the API?
2. How should the API be prepared in `plumber` to receive time series data?

Below is some example data and a function which accomplishes what I would like in R.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# data to be passed to API
head(forecast::wineind,14)
#>        Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov
#> 1980 15136 16733 20016 17708 18019 19227 22893 23739 21133 22591 26786
#> 1981 15028 17977                                                      
#>        Dec
#> 1980 29740
#> 1981

#* Return Forecast Data
#* @list a The first number
#* @get /simple_fcast
function(){
  ts() %>% 
  forecast::ets() %>% 
  forecast::forecast()
}
#> function(){
#>   ts() %>% 
#>   forecast::ets() %>% 
#>   forecast::forecast()
#> }
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use "message body" per the documentation here https://www.rplumber.io/docs/routing-and-input.html#

```
#' @post /user
function(req, id, name){
  list(
    id = id,
    name = name,
    raw = req$postBody
  )
}
```

Running `curl --data "id=123&name=Jennifer" "http://localhost:8000/user"` will return:

```
{
  "id": [123],
  "name": ["Jennifer"],
  "raw": ["id=123&name=Jennifer"]
}
```

I found that arrays can also be passed to functions.